# $\sup_{x \in S} |\overline{P}P(x)| = [\sup_{x \in S} |P(x)]^2$,

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How does it follow that, given a polynomial $P$ over $\mathbb{C}$,

$$\sup_{x\in S} \left| \overline{P}\,P(x) \right| = \left[ \sup_{x\in S} \left| P(x) \right| \right]^2$$

where $S$ is some set, and $\overline{P}$ is the conjugate of $P$?

I'm thinking $\left|\overline{P}\,P(x)\right| \leq \left|P^2(x)\right| \leq \left|P(x)\right|^2$ can show one direction. Not sure about the other.

Comment: Did you mean the following? $$\sup_{x\in S} \left| \overline{P}P(x) \right| = \left[ \sup_{x\in S} \left| P(x) \right| \right]^2$$ (Notice the second $|$ beside $P(x)$ on the righthand side.)

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor thanks

Comment: I’ve just suggested some edits to your [MathJax markdown](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I think they will more clearly communicate what you intend. You'll be able to see them once they are approved by another editor $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\overline PP=|P|^2$, $\sup_{x \in S} |\overline{P}P(x)| =\sup_{x \in S} (|P(x)|^2)$.

It remains to prove $\sup_{x \in S} (|P(x)|^2)=(\sup_{x \in S} |P(x)|)^2$.

Since $|P(x)|\leq \sup_{x\in S}|P(x)|$, squaring yields $|P(x)|^2\leq (\sup_{x\in S}|P(x)|)^2$. This holds for any $x\in S$, hence  $\sup_{x \in S} (|P(x)|^2)\leq(\sup_{x \in S} |P(x)|)^2$

Since $|P(x)|^2\leq \sup_{x\in S}(|P(x)|^2)$, taking the square root yields $|P(x)|\leq \sqrt{(\sup_{x \in S} |P(x)|^2)}$. This holds for any $x\in S$, hence $\sup_{x\in S} |P(x)|\leq \sqrt{(\sup_{x \in S} |P(x)|^2)}$, that is $(\sup_{x\in S} |P(x)|)^2\leq (\sup_{x \in S} |P(x)|^2)$.

Thus $\sup_{x \in S} (|P(x)|^2)=(\sup_{x \in S} |P(x)|)^2$.

Comment: thanks for the answer!